# Change column header name dynamically in React Table

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-table

I am using React Table in my dashboard project. I want to change the React Table column header name on every tab click. I am passing the name state as props in React table, but the Header text is not changing as per the props. Is this possible to change Column header inside it ?

Below is the code of react table component in which the tabName is the state that i am passing as props, which is not changing.

```
const BreakdownTable = ({ tabName }) => {
  // console.log(tabName);
  const data = React.useMemo(
    () => [
      {
        col1: "com.gumlet.limited-videoPlay",
        col2: "100",
        col3: "1.3k",
      },
    ],
    []
  );

  const columns = React.useMemo(
    () => [
      {
        Header: tabName,
        accessor: "col1",
      },
      {
        Header: "Unique Views",
        accessor: "col2",
      },
      {
        Header: "Total Views",
        accessor: "col3",
      },
    ],
    []
  );

  const {
    getTableProps,
    getTableBodyProps,
    headerGroups,
    // rows,
    prepareRow,
    page,
    canPreviousPage,
    canNextPage,
    pageOptions,
    // pageCount,
    gotoPage,
    nextPage,
    // previousPage,
    setPageSize,
    pageSize,
    state,
    setGlobalFilter,
  } = useTable(
    {
      columns,
      data,
      initialState: { pageSize: 15 },
    },
    useGlobalFilter,
    useSortBy,
    usePagination
  );

  const { globalFilter } = state;
```

Comment: Try removing the use.Memo on the columns function. As well as pass tabname as a parameter in the column function

Comment: @SachinVishwakarma  It won't render header now after removing use.Memo .. and showing render error while passing tabname as parameter...!!!

Answer (score 0):

can you try making column like this, a simple plain javascript array? This will help to determine if the issue is because of useMemo function.

```
const columns = [
  {
    Header: tabName,
    accessor: "col1",
  },
  {
    Header: "Unique Views",
    accessor: "col2",
  },
  {
    Header: "Total Views",
    accessor: "col3",
  },
]
```

Comment: Not working . Showing Error: Maximum update depth exceeded. This can happen when a component repeatedly calls setState inside react hook.

Comment: Can you upload your code snippet on codesandbox.io site. This will help to identify the root cause.

Comment: https://codesandbox.io/s/spring-cloud-iymd0?file=/src/App.js

here is the link.. Just added the 2 files. You can check...!!